# getting error ImportError: No module named 'odoo.report' in odoo 11

Tags: odoo

I'm getting an error

ImportError: No module named 'odoo.report'

while converting my codes from odoo version 10 to odoo version 11. 
My code is given below and how can I use those following code in Odoo 11?

```
from odoo.report.render.rml2pdf import utils
from odoo.report.render.rml2pdf import color
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In odoo 11 no need to use odoo.report lib. It is deprecated. You can use `odoo.tools` insted of that.

Just import it with following statement:

```
from odoo.tools import report
```

Comment: This odoo.tolls is not availble  in Odoo11. Then how can i use this ?

Comment: It is always available. Because it is in odoo core base. Just in header write like : " from odoo.tools import"   and you will able to import it.

Comment: Yes so, how can I use this rml2pdf ?

Comment: Why you want  use rml2pdf in 11 ? What you want to achieve ?

Comment: Thanks for spending time for my issue. I'm trying to migrate a module from version 10 to 11. In version 10, I created a module which prints the tree view like in the given attachments. So, I use odoo.report package, and fucntions in utils.py and colors.py for this. But it's not found in odoo 11. I want to take a printout like following:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwSKRFuzxE8ucjRzWkNDRG5qOFRYZkVzaGp6UGtCeUVYc0Fv

Comment: comment continues...

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwSKRFuzxE8uM2JRN1JobnZOa215SVk2TzNQTXB5WlJHa2lB

Comment: I can not access your drive.

Comment: Please go through this link :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzTT5LxMvuHnNFNSeGdqSkFkeXM 

and 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzTT5LxMvuHnM0U1RzV4dFZnckU

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157574/discussion-between-nidhinmohancheriyan-and-keval-mehta).