# How to customize reports in Odoo 11 in Qweb? How to send data from other model to the qweb report?

Tags: report, odoo, qweb, odoo-11

Does someone know a way to change the source of docs in a custom report? I need to load dataset from a view inherited from my model. Columns are the same than the model, it's just a data filter.

Answer (score 3):

In v11, report module has been removed along with report object. For this reason, you are facing this error. You have to remove the report from depends as it is added / merged in base module. You can check it here.

You can call your report using report_action method as follow:

```
self.env.ref('your_report_name').report_action(self, data=data)
```

Hope this will help you and solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Odoo 11

There is no need to use `odoo.report` library anymore. It is deprecated. You can use odoo.tools insted of that:

```py
from odoo.tools import report
```

As it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46902355/4891717)

And you can send data as Muhsin k says in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48049244/4891717)

```
self.env.ref('your_report_name').report_action(self, data=data)
```

### Previous Odoo versions

You have all the documentation [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/reports.html). Anyway if you wan to customize the data that you can use in a report you can use a method like this:

```py
from odoo import api, models

class ParticularReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.module.report_name'
    @api.model
    def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
        report_obj = self.env['report']
        report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('module.report_name')

        custom_data = self.env['model.name'].get_data()

        docargs = {
            'doc_ids': docids,
            'doc_model': report.model,
            'docs': self,
            'custom_data': custom_data,
        }
        return report_obj.render('module.report_name', docargs)
```

The model `model.name` is the model where you want to get the information

### Inherit Qweb Templates

The tag `template` is a shortcut for some views. The `inherit_id` attribute can be used here as well. Most of report are build with this kind of view:

```xml
<template id='report_invoice_document' inherit_id='account.report_invoice_document'>
    <xpath expr="//p[@t-if='o.payment_term.note']" position="after">

        <!-- You can use you data object here -->

    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: I already know the documentation location and you just copy-past it. This is useless. I am looking for a way or an exemple about how to replace the full dataset of a report by a view with same columns.

Comment: Sure, but you don't need anything else. You can send all the information that you want to the report with that method. I have added a `custom_data` to my answer in order to clearify it

Comment: Probably my problem come from I don't understand how to make my model point at the view instead of the table. In my idea just one model is needing...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? I can show you a complete report example if it helps you

Comment: @ChesuCR I had not found render_html() base method in Odoo 11.I think the question he asked is totally different version and you are answering them is also the different version.

Comment: @dasadiya Uhmm I didn't work with Odoo v11 yet, but I copied the example from the Odoo v11 documentation. Do you mean that the documentatios is wrong and they have change the way to add custom data to the report? I think the parent method should be in the `report` module, but I didn't check it neither

Comment: The document is totally part of older version other then odoo V11 and also one more important things report module is totally removed from the V11 and merge with base module. just check and see the code and change your answer.

Comment: OK, this is new info for me, thank you. I will check it later if I have free time

Comment: Yes sure you can check it on your free time

Comment: there is no report module in odoo.tools

Comment: there is  no env['report'] on odoo11!

Comment: That is why I write for "Previous Odoo versions" @m3asmi. It is just extra information

Answer (score 0):

the `render_html` was replaced with the function `get_report_values` :

```
    @api.model
    def get_report_values(self, docids, data=None): 
        docs = self.env['model.name'].browse(docids)
        return {
             'doc_ids': docids,
             'doc_model': 'model.name',
             'docs': docs,
             'lines': self.some_func(docs),
             'data': data,
        }
```